# C# WPF MVVM Adding data to a collection in another ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am new to MVVM so bare with me.

I attempt to create a server application GUI which contains two buttons (start- and stop server) and a Listbox, which contains the name of connected players. Here is an image for better visual understanding:

[image]

**What I want to do:**
In LoginCommand.cs, which is created in the ServerManager.cs, I want to access and add the player name of the incoming client connection to the ObservableCollection Players in the PlayerViewModel (which is also the ItemSource of the ListBox in PlayerView). How can I do this (code is below)?

**Project structure:**

[image]

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="MVVMTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MVVMTest.View"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="200">

    <StackPanel>
        <views:ServerView x:Name="ServerView" DataContext="{Binding ServerViewModel}" />
        <views:PlayerView x:Name="PlayerView" DataContext="{Binding PlayerViewModel}" Height="330" />
    </StackPanel>

</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using MVVMTest.ViewModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace MVVMTest
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainViewModel MainViewModel { get; set; }
        public MainWindow()
        {
            MainViewModel = new MainViewModel();
            DataContext = MainViewModel;
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

**MainViewModel.cs**

```
namespace MVVMTest.ViewModel
{
    public class MainViewModel
    {
        public ServerViewModel ServerViewModel { get; set; }

        public PlayerViewModel PlayerViewModel { get; set; }

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            ServerViewModel = new ServerViewModel();
            PlayerViewModel = new PlayerViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

**PlayerView.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="MVVMTest.View.PlayerView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="790" d:DesignWidth="200" Background="White">
    <GroupBox Header="Players">
        <ListBox x:Name="listBoxPlayers" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Players}"></ListBox>
    </GroupBox>
</UserControl>
```

**PlayerViewModel.cs**

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace MVVMTest.ViewModel
{
    public class PlayerViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<string> Players { get; set; }

        public PlayerViewModel() 
        {
            Players = new ObservableCollection<string>
            {
                "Player1",
                "Player2"
            };
        }

    }
}
```

**ServerView.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="MVVMTest.View.ServerView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="110" d:DesignWidth="200" Background="White">

    <GroupBox Grid.Column="0" Header="Server Properties">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="30" />
                <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Button Grid.Row="0" Content="Start Server" Command="{Binding Path=StartServerCommand}" Margin="3 5 3 0" />
            <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Stop Server" Command="{Binding Path=StopServerCommand}" Margin="3 5 3 0" />
        </Grid>
    </GroupBox>
</UserControl>
```

**ServerViewModel.cs**

```
using MVVMTest.Command;
using MVVMTest.Manager;
using MVVMTest.Model;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace MVVMTest.ViewModel
{
    public class ServerViewModel
    {
        private Task _serverTask;
        private CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource;
        private readonly ServerManager _serverManager;
        private readonly ServerModel _serverModel;

        public bool IsRunning => _serverModel.IsRunning;

        private readonly RelayCommand _startServerCommand;
        private readonly RelayCommand _stopServerCommand;
        public ICommand StartServerCommand => _startServerCommand;
        public ICommand StopServerCommand => _stopServerCommand;

        public ServerViewModel()
        {
            _serverModel = new ServerModel();
            _serverManager = new ServerManager();
            _startServerCommand = new RelayCommand(OnStartServer, CanStartServer);
            _stopServerCommand = new RelayCommand(OnStopServer, CanStopServer);
        }

        private void OnStartServer(object command)
        {
            _serverModel.IsRunning = true;
            _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            _serverTask = new Task(_serverManager.Start, _cancellationTokenSource.Token);
            _serverTask.Start();

            _startServerCommand.InvokeCanExecuteChanged();
            _stopServerCommand.InvokeCanExecuteChanged();
        }

        private void OnStopServer(object command)
        {
            if (_serverTask != null && _cancellationTokenSource != null)
            {
                _serverModel.IsRunning = false;
                _serverManager.Stop();
                _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
                _startServerCommand.InvokeCanExecuteChanged();
                _stopServerCommand.InvokeCanExecuteChanged();
            }
        }

        private bool CanStartServer(object command) => !IsRunning;
        private bool CanStopServer(object command) => IsRunning;
    }
}
```

**ServerManager.cs**

```
using MVVMTest.Command;
using System;

namespace MVVMTest.Manager
{
    public class ServerManager
    {
        enum PacketType
        {
            Login
        }

        public ServerManager()  {}

        public void Start()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Server is starting...");

            // Fake method that we are listening to incoming connections
            while (true)
            {
                // Fake read incoming packettype
                PacketType incomingPacket = PacketType.Login;

                if (incomingPacket == PacketType.Login)
                {
                    string playerName = "Test"; // Pretend this is incoming data from client

                    LoginCommand loginCommand = new LoginCommand();
                    loginCommand.Run(playerName);

                    // Reply back to client
                }
            }            
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Server is stopping...");
        }
    }
}
```

**LoginCommand.cs**

```
namespace MVVMTest.Command
{
    class LoginCommand : IServerCommand
    {
        public void Run(string incomingData)
        {
            // HERE I WANT TO ADD incomingData to listBoxPlayers in PlayerView.xaml
            // listBoxPlayers.Add(incomingData);
            // How can I achieve this?
        }
    }
}
```

**IServerCommand.cs**

```
namespace MVVMTest.Command
{
    interface IServerCommand
    {
        void Run(string incomingData);
    }
}
```

**ServerModel.cs**

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace MVVMTest.Model
{
    public class ServerModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool isRunning = default;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public ServerModel()
        {
            IsRunning = false;
        }

        public bool IsRunning
        {
            get => isRunning;
            set
            {
                isRunning = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(IsRunning));
            }
        }

        private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

**RelayCommand.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace MVVMTest.Command
{
    class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        private readonly Action<object> _executeAction;
        private readonly Func<object, bool> _canExecuteAction;

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> executeAction, Func<object, bool> canExecuteAction)
        {
            _executeAction = executeAction;
            _canExecuteAction = canExecuteAction;
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter) => _executeAction(parameter);
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => _canExecuteAction?.Invoke(parameter) ?? true;
        public void InvokeCanExecuteChanged() => CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like PlayerView.xaml has the duplicated code of LoginCommand.cs. And before continue, can you explain what are the purpose of your ServerManager and LoginCommand?

Comment: Thanks for noticing! I updated the PlayerView.cs
The responsibility of the ServerManager.cs is to deal with all server-related logic, e.g. listen to incoming packets. The purpose of the LoginCommand is to handle specifically incoming login attempts (PacketType.Login). There will also be a LogoutCommand for when players logout (PacketType.LogOut). My question however, is solely focused on how to access the collection from the PlayerViewModel in an efficient way that is ok in MVVM standard :)

Comment: MVVM is about the relation between your model, your view and your viewmodel. Here you are asking about how `LoginCommand` can access a viewmodel (`PlayerViewModel`), which has many ways to do. You can just pass `PlayerViewModel`to `ServerViewModel` constructor, then pass it to `ServerManager` and then to `LoginCommand`.

Comment: @robtot: You may for example use an event aggreator or a messenger to send an event/message from one view model to another in a loosely coupled way.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. This guide https://www.technical-recipes.com/2016/using-the-mediator-pattern-in-mvvm-wpf/ helped me solve my challenges.